# selenium standalone server 2.25 time out error

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to increase the timeout time for my scripts. How do I do this?

So far, I have:

```
java -jar /var/www/sites/all/srk_tests/test_data/selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -userExtensions /var/www/sites/all/srk_tests/user-extensions.js -timeout 40000  -htmlSuite *firefox mysiteurlhere /var/www/sites/all/srk_tests/organization_test/organization_test_ts.html /var/www/sites/all/srk_tests/test_results/organization_test_results.html
```

But the "-timeout 40000" does not work.

I am trying to allow a command in my script enough time to finish running and not time out after 30000ms

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium RC :

```
selenium.setTimeout("40000");
```

Selenium WebDriver :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```